# How do I write a bash script to compare and output values in any .txt files that have the same format?

Tags: bash, shell, compare

How do I write a bash script to compare any .txt file with the **SAME** format as what I listed below and output them using grep?

first column is a bunch of ID's, each have a score of 1 or 0. ID 123 has 2 attempts, that's why I divide over 6 instead of 3.

Please Note, I'm not comparing file1.txt to file2.txt necessarily. Pretend there's more .txt files with this format that you're trying to find the average of different ID's (some are in more than one file such as ID 123).

file1.txt

```
CourseA

123   1 1 1
456   1 0 1
789   0 0 0
```

file2.txt

```
CourseB

123   1 0 1
233   0 1 0
423   0 0 1
```

My Desired Output

```
ID     CourseA    CourseB     AVG
123      3/3        2/3       5/6
456      2/3         -        2/3
789      0/3         -        0/3
233       -         1/3       1/3
423       -         1/3       1/3
```

Comment: Do it with `awk`. Create associative arrays with all the data for each course. Then at the end, loop through the arrays combining the data and calculating the averages.

Comment: This would probably be easier in a better language like Python, using a library like pandas.

Comment: @Barmar Do you know of any way of doing it using grep? I'm just trying to learn as I recently started and haven't started with awk yet. I'm trying to familiarize myself with the basics. Even then, I have no clue how to use awk.

Comment: This can't be done with just `grep`. It just prints matching rows, it can't reorganize it or perform calculations.

Comment: @Barmar Also, when you say "Create associative arrays", what if there are 10+ files with way more data, how can I possibly do that?

Comment: That's another reason why this would be easier in a better language. You need multidimensional arrays.

Comment: You need 2 dimensions: course name and student ID.

Comment: I see. I have managed to find the AVG for example but only if I compare user input with the ID's. For example, if the user types 123, it will list the AVG which is 5/6. I used for loops and a couple of if statements (Its kind of a long code so didn't want to list it here).

Comment: If you want to do it using `grep` that's what you'd have to do. It will have to reread all the files for each student ID

Comment: My main problem is how do I compare ID 123 for example and output the ID with the GPA? I've also tried creating a method that lists all the ID's in a temp file, but how do I compare those ID's inside the temp file to the AVG and output them the way I want to? I'm probably asking for too much here xD

Comment: You need to get all the IDs into an array. Then you can loop through the array and search for matches in all the files to calculate the AVG.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

file='./file*.txt'

# list of headers
columns=$(head -qn1 $file | grep -oE '^\S+' | sort | uniq)

# list of items
items=$(tail -qn+2 $file | grep -oE '^\S+' | sort | uniq)

# print table header
echo "ID\t${columns//$'\n'/$'\t'}\tAVG"

# generate table sequencial
for item in $items
  do
    unset i j
    # summate values overall files
    for n in $(grep -h ^$item $file | grep -oE '(\s+[0-9]+)')
      do
        i=$((i+n))
        j=$((j+1))
    done

    # print next line
    printf "%s\t" $item

    # print columns
    for column in $columns
      do
        # query all files for columns
        grep -q ^$column $(grep -l ^$item $file)
        if [ $? != 0 ]
          then
            # item does not exist in this file
            printf "-\t"
          else
            # print values for column
            printf "%d %d %d\t" $(grep -h ^$item $(grep -l ^$column $file) | grep -oE '(\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+)')
        fi
    done

    # print sum
    printf "%d/%d\n" $i $j
done
```

Comment: only for words and file names without whitespace

Comment: Thanks for the code. However, I get this error 233     a: line 36: printf: -\: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]

Comment: For the most part your code makes sense to me. Its really close to what I wanted other than that error I mentioned

Comment: could only test on android busybox because have no access to PC. replace the line with `printf "%s\t" "  -  "`

Comment: You mentioned its only for words without whitespace, lets say I switch CourseA to Course A or Course: Section A. It obviously won't work from your code. I would use cut but it messes the spaces up. Also, how do I change the AVG if I want to add another line in the .txt files of lets say, course worth. So next line after Course A is Worth - 2 and line after Course B is Worth - 1. For example, ID 123 has a 3/3 in Course A and 2/3 in B. But Course A is worth double now so it will affect the AVG since it holds more weight.

Comment: For the AVG issue above, I tried adding courseWorth = $(grep 'Worth' $??? cut -d '-' -f2) inside the first for loop, and then multiply n * courseWorth and j=$((j+courseWorth)). The ??? is what am I supposed to add here? I can't use $item because it makes no sense. So I how do I do it? Thanks

Comment: add the `-w` flag to `grep ^$item` to avoid *"Course"* matching *"CourseA"*. and just don't use whitespace at all. replace all with `_` like `Course_A` (and replace it back when `echo` the header line). or use arrays instead of strings (limited to bash)